# ArrayIndexOutofBoundException in Split text processor

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I am using nifi 1.1.1 package. I applied the patch files in the source code by referring the below link:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/1214/files.

Now split text processor works fine, if the header line count given as 0 and above 1.

Split text processor splits the data properly and generates flow file, if the input file contains 10000 rows or below 10000 rows.

If the input file contains more than 20000 rows then it would not splits the data and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occured.

Please find the below error details.
[image]